# how do i call a method from a usecontrol to a another usercontrol?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

I have a usercontrol where in I add/update data and save it to a database and i want the datagrid to refresh right a way using my method refreshDVG1();

```
    public void refreshDVG1()
    {
        try
        {
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Selected = this.dataGridView1[0, 0].Selected;
            datset.Clear();
            sda.Fill(datset);
            dataGridView1.Refresh();
            if (dataGridView1.RowCount < 1)
            {

                    datset.Clear();

                    string row = "NO items found";
                    datset.Rows.Add(row);


            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
        }

    }`
```

but it doesn't seems to be working and tried using the method on a button on the same usercontrol of the datagridview and it works fine so I dont know why I get an error btw the error I receive was I was receiving a nullrefernce object or something..I'm new to c# so I kind off mess up this one I hope you help me in this problem

code for update and please note that this is from he different usercontrol and both two usercontrol are on the same form

```
<br><i>private void UpdateAcc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SuspendLayout();
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection))
            {
                string query = "UPDATE `deqor`.`users` SET `first_name`=?name, `middle_name`=?mname, `last_name`=?lname WHERE `userid`=?para;";
                conn.Open();
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?name", Fname.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?mname", Mname.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?lname", Lname.Text);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?para", manageACC.staticNumData);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        MessageBox.Show("success");

                            //MainForm main = Form.ActiveForm as MainForm;
                            manageACC main1 = this.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent as manageACC;
                            main1.refreshDVG1();

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("error" + ex);
                    }

                }

                conn.Close();
            }
            ResumeLayout();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve this approach, one of them is you can create Event on second usercontrol and raise it when click on button, then in form container handle that event and in handler call the first UserControl method.
The another way you can pass the first UserControl in second one and call the method directly.

You can find another solution in [this place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386572/how-can-i-call-method-from-usercontrol-from-another-usercontrol-using-asp-net)

It depends on your code, archticture and project structure. Can not offer a answer fr your question.

If you want to find the best solution, you can add more details.

```
public partial class edit : UserControl
{
     public EventHandler DataUpdated; 
}

private void UpdateAcc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Saving Data In DB

   //MainForm main = Form.ActiveForm as MainForm;
   //manageACC main1 = this.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent as manageACC;
   //main1.refreshDVG1();
   //Instead of commented code raise the event
   if(DataUpdated != null)
      DataUpdated(this, System.eventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Then in main form code behind handle the DataUpdated event:

```
//edit1 imagine is id of second usercontrol instance
edit1.DataUpdated += (s,e) => 
{
    //you have usercontrol1 instance here, so just call method directly here
    //manageACC1imagine is id of first usercontrol instance
    manageACC1.refreshDVG1();
}
```

Comment: if its ok I can send you the whole code of that form(not the whole project) and stored it on a note pad you can check that if its ok for you

Comment: How do i attach the rar file here it contains 2 codes and a screenshot

Comment: It.s better upload somewhere and put link here

Comment: Ok I saw your code, If I were you I use the first option that already I mentioned, created event and handle in Main Form, do you know how to implement it?

Comment: uhhm where do I put the edit1.DataUpdated += (s,e) => ??in my main form? or in the main usercontrol?

Comment: main form, the container of both usercontrol, you can put in Form load, or after initialize controls

Comment: the container of the both user control was a panel within the main form so do I paste the uhhm  edit1.DataUpdated += (s,e) => in the event of panel or the mainform? and what event? sorry for being noob here Y.Y

Comment: no, I mean the Class container, not component. Cause you can put both control in another UserControl or can put both directly in Form. So in this case your container class is Form

Comment: tried putting in the mainform's load event and also inside the InitializeComponent(); but it seems not working got alot of error hmmp

Comment: I'm sure it's working, but is hard to chat here. Do you know any place that can chat about it?

Comment: facebook or skype sorry for being late reply..just finished eating lunch

Comment: you can check my mainform here http://www.mediafire.com/view/88vb6g10227ozf8/mainform.txt

Comment: seems like i've solve it on my own thanks for the help

Comment: Good, did you use my solution or found another one?

Comment: I've understand your codes properly now and it was a best solution but after experimenting many things i've found another solution and it was way shorter code so right now still testing which loads faster than the two solution,anyway thanks for the help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73387/discussion-between-peyman-and-raymart-calinao-asthrea).